# Is it OK to Render an array of components in React 16?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was informed by a fellow developer that is is considered bad practice to render an array of components in React 16?

Is this so?

Comment: Your question is off topic for stackoverflow, but I'm still curious: what is the alternative good practice this fellow dev suggests...?

Comment: @ChrisG May I know which one it rather belongs to?

Comment: I just become react enthusiast recently. It is kind new for me about "Array of components". May i know what is that?

Answer (score 4):

Btw, React 16.2 has arrived with Fragments! (don't forget to update both react and react-dom)

```
return (
 <>
  <El1 />
  <El2 />
  <El3 />
 </>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The new thing about arrays in react 16 is that you don't have to wrap them with containing element (on render).

In react 15 you had to:

```
let data = [
    <li key="1">One</li>,
    <li key="2">Two</li>,
    <li key="3">Three</li>
];
return (<div>{data}</div>);
```

While in react 16 you can just:

```
let data = [
    { value: "One", key: "1" },
    { value: "Two", key: "2" },
    { value: "Three", key: "3" }
];
return data.map(item => {
    return (
        <li key={item.key}>
            {item.value}
        </li>
    );
});
```

Or even simpler:

```
render() {
    return [
        <li key="A">First item</li>,
        <li key="B">Second item</li>,
        <li key="C">Third item</li>,
    ];
}
```